# How to move position in Quick Launch

Tags: quick-launch

I tried to order, movenode position in quick launch. Is there any alternative ways to do so?

```
    private void MoveNodeToPosition(int positionToMoveTo, int postionInTarget, SPWeb localWeb)
          {

             var ql = localWeb.Navigation.QuickLaunch;
             if (positionToMoveTo == postionInTarget) return;
             if (positionToMoveTo == 0)
             {
                  localWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                  ql[postionInTarget].MoveToFirst(ql);
                     localWeb.Update();
                    return;
             }            
                if (positionToMoveTo < ql.Count)
                {
                //positionToMoveTo = positionToMoveTo - ql.Count;
                localWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                 ql[postionInTarget].Move(ql, ql[positionToMoveTo - 1]); 
                 localWeb.Update();
             }
         }
```

Comment: Hope this helps

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041775/best-way-to-programmatically-create-maintain-sharepoint-quick-launch-menu

Answer (score 1):

1.Go to Root Site in Web Application

2.Site Action->Look and feel->Quick launch->change order

Comment: I want to do it programmatically.